# Linq query to nest 3 tables and select certain records

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I'm building a simple tour booking app.

It has 3 linked tables, setup as below.

Given a specific TourCategoryId and a date (dte), I'm trying to build an object which I can then go on to populate a viewmodel with.

However I'm not understanding how to check the TourDate field against dte.

Am I trying to do too much in one statement?  Can anyone help me with what I thought would be a simple query?

Thanks for any advice:

My linq is:

```
var tours = db.Tours
            .Include(x => x.TourDate)
            .Include(x => x.TourDate.Select(b => b.Booking))
            .Where(t => t.TourCategoryId == id &&
                        t.TourDate.Any(td => td.Date==dte));
```

(also pseudo code)

```
            .Where(v => v.Booking.NumberBooked.Sum() < v.Tours.PlacesAvailable)
```

I've updated this with suggestions below, but it is returning all `td.Date` - and not filtering, as you can see from the screenshot below, showing all 3 records returned, and not just those where `td.Date == dte`:

Is it the .Any that is maybe not correct?

The end result should be

List of Tours => List of Dates => List of Bookings - where the dates are filtered to the `dte` eg:

```
Tour1- night tours
--TourDate - filtered to 02/03/2015
----Booking1
----Booking2
----Booking3
Tour2- day tours
--TourDate - filtered to 02/03/2015
----Booking1
----Booking2
Tour3- multi-day tours
--TourDate - filtered to 02/03/2015
----Booking1
----Booking2
----Booking3
----Booking4
```

Thanks again, Mark

[image: Screenshot from VS]

```
public class Tour
{
    public int TourId { get; set; }
    public int TourCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string TourName { get; set; }
    public int PlacesAvailable { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TourDate> TourDate { get; set; }
}

public class TourDate
{
    public int TourDateId { get; set; }
    public int TourId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual Tour Tour { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Booking> Booking { get; set; }
}

public class Booking
{
    public int BookingId { get; set; }
    public int TourDateId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int NumberBooked { get; set; }
    public virtual TourDate TourDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Should probably be `.Where(t => t.TourCategoryId == id && t.TourDate.Any(td => td.Date == dte))`

Comment: What exactly do you want your end result output to be?

Comment: Hi - I've added the desired output in now.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want any `Tour` in `TourCategoryId` which has a `TourDate` on `dte`.

This may work for you.

```
var tours =
    db.Tours
        .Include(x => x.TourDate)
        .Include(x => x.TourDate.Select(b => b.Booking))
        .Where(t => t.TourCategoryId == id &&
                    t.TourDate.Any(td => td.Date == dte));
```

To filter the `TourDate`.

```
foreach(var tour in tours)
{
    tour.TourDate = tour.TourDate.Where(td => td.Date == dte).ToList()
}
```

Comment: Hi - thank you for your input.  It's still showing all 3 records however - but I've updated with screenshots above.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous as to what output you are expecting. Can you clarify?

Comment: Hi - there are 3 records in the TourDate table - with dates of 01/03/2015, 02/03/2015, 03/03/2015 - with the filter of t.TourDate.Any(td => td.Date==dte) - where dte= 02/03/2015 - there should only be 1 result - however in the screenshot, there are 3 - for each of the records shown.  Thanks Romoku - sorry if I'm not clear

Comment: The linq query is returning `Tour` objects that contain the date. Do you want the `TourDate` objects and not the `Tour` objects?

Comment: Hi - I wanted both Tours -> TourDates -> Bookings - am I making it too complicated to do as one query

Comment: You either need to return `TourDate` from the linq query or use a separate step to filter the collection.

Comment: ok thank you - I've got LinqPad - I'll keep working in that and see if I can break it up - I really appreciate your help, Mark

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that the business object you work with does not fit in the class hierarchy you use.

Try not to work strictly with the database mapped classes. Your business objects in this case are something different from just a list of instances of the Tour class that are matched to the db strucure. Just use the db classes to form a query, with the help of all the navigation properties you created, but dont try to fit all the queries you need to the same class hierarchy as you need for a view model.

You should build your query around bookings, not tours. select the bookings matching your criteria, including the one in pseudocode, then group by the dates and tours and select some kind of anonimous object, representing the groups. Then translate those to view model classes you need, not necessary all of which are database mapped.

In many cases, you do not even need ro hydrate an entity just to get some property loaded.

No need to load an elephant just to be able to take a picture.
`Include` is really just a workaround, like killing the elephant and loading by parts.